# toast notification in windows phone 8 - stream error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have download toast notification sample code from microsoft site but the code is not executed properly -- giving an error in httpwebresponse --

```
    protected void ButtonSendToast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    // Get the Uri that the Microsoft Push Notification Service returns to the Push Client when creating a notification channel.
    // Normally, a web service would listen for Uri's coming from the web client and maintain a list of Uri's to send
    // notifications out to.
    string subscriptionUri = TextBoxUri.Text.ToString();


    HttpWebRequest sendNotificationRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(subscriptionUri);

    // We will create a HTTPWebRequest that posts the toast notification to the Microsoft Push Notification Service.
    // HTTP POST is the only allowed method to send the notification.
    sendNotificationRequest.Method = "POST";

    // The optional custom header X-MessageID uniquely identifies a notification message. 
    // If it is present, the // same value is returned in the notification response. It must be a string that contains a UUID.
    // sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-MessageID", "<UUID>");

    // Create the toast message.
    string toastMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
    "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
       "<wp:Toast>" +
            "<wp:Text1>" + TextBoxTitle.Text.ToString() + "</wp:Text1>" +
            "<wp:Text2>" + TextBoxSubTitle.Text.ToString() + "</wp:Text2>" +
            "<wp:Param>/Page2.xaml?NavigatedFrom=Toast Notification</wp:Param>" +
       "</wp:Toast> " +
    "</wp:Notification>";

    // Sets the notification payload to send.
    byte[] notificationMessage = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(toastMessage);

    // Sets the web request content length.
    sendNotificationRequest.ContentLength = notificationMessage.Length;
    sendNotificationRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
    sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-WindowsPhone-Target", "toast");
    sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-NotificationClass", "2");

    using (Stream requestStream = sendNotificationRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        requestStream.Write(notificationMessage, 0, notificationMessage.Length);
    }

    // Send the notification and get the response.
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)sendNotificationRequest.GetResponse();   // Exception in this line
    string notificationStatus = response.Headers["X-NotificationStatus"];
    string notificationChannelStatus = response.Headers["X-SubscriptionStatus"];
    string deviceConnectionStatus = response.Headers["X-DeviceConnectionStatus"];

    // Display the response from the Microsoft Push Notification Service.  
    // Normally, error handling code would be here.  In the real world, because data connections are not always available,
    // notifications may need to be throttled back if the device cannot be reached.
    TextBoxResponse.Text = notificationStatus + " | " + deviceConnectionStatus + " | " + notificationChannelStatus;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    TextBoxResponse.Text = "Exception caught sending update: " + ex.ToString();
  }

}
```

}

I tried running this code in vs 2010 and vs 2013 express but still got the same error